# Implementing chandy-lamport algorithm in Kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm working on a CDC platform using Kafka and Kafka Connector.
I'm using multiple topics for sinking data. However, in some cases, I need to ensure the correct order of records that are located in different topics.
I understand this is a common challenge in distributed computing, and I'm exploring ways to handle it.
I'm wondering if it's possible to implement the Chandy-Lamport algorithm within the Kafka sink connector's source code. If not, what other approaches would you recommend for implementing it?

I don't know much about this field yet, so the question may be strange.

Thanks.

I just checked which records are stored in each topic.